# Spring and Hibernate, Lazy initiation problem

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, lazy-loading

Hey I am developing an desktop application using Spring and Hibernate, and I have a problem with lazy initiation. I looked in the web and every solution is related to the open session in view pattern, but I can't use this pattern. I've also tried to get the `sessionfactory` from the `HibernateTemplate`, but it returns to me a disconnected session.

Does anyone know other solution?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Got any hbms and cfgs files for us? You really need to give us more detail.

Comment: I believe you that you can't use the Open Session in View pattern, but I'm curious as to why that is.  Can you elaborate a bit on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you basically have two solutions:

1. Make arrangements to keep a Hibernate session open when you access a lazy-initialized object or collection.  That means you're going to have to carefully mark your transaction boundaries in your code, a la the "open session in view" pattern.  Spring makes this possible, but in a desktop application it won't be as straightforward as a web application where the transaction boundaries are a little more obvious.
2. Turn off all the lazy-initialization for your persisted objects in Hibernate.

Option 2 could lead to a lot of unnecessary database access, and option 1 means you have to seriously study your workflow and use cases.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I done something similar to first option...
I have changed the Application Context to make transaction boundaries in every business class methods.  thanks mojo

Answer (score 1):

One option is to call Hibernate.initialize() on the entities or collections to force initialize them. You'd want to do this before you return the data back to your view. I would consider this carefully, since it's going to generate a lot of SQL statements back to the database.

You may want to look into using "fetch" in your HQL queries or configuration the fetch mode to "eager" in your mappings (I believe it's FetchMode.EAGER in JPA or lazy="false" in hbm.xml).

@Jose: Don't manage the Session in your own ThreadLocal.  Use SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() and configure Hibernate to use the "thread" SessionContext.

Comment: i have tried this way but i doesn't work.
The spring works with one session per operation, so when i try to call any Hibernate methods it says that there is no session or the session is closed.  any way thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem, and as I was not able to find any really appropriate solution to it. I came up with my own one combining a lot of different approaches found on the web and posted them to my blog.

Sorry, that I don't put it in all here, but it is to much work to do it over and over again in all the forums I found people having this or a similar problem

[Remote Lazy Loading with Hibernate and Spring](http://hons82.blogspot.com/2010/12/remote-lazy-loading-with-hibernate-and.html)